# Script in jquery to valide a form not work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I made a form to insert a new product on my site, and i want to validate it with js, but it don't work and i don't know why.
I have no errors in the console but nothing of the code work. I use the same code to validate a login form and it works so i don't know why here not working.
If you can help me to find the mistakes
Here is the js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    const form = $('#form');
    const title =  $('#title');
    const descr =  $('#descr');
    const budget = $('#budget');

    form.submit(e => {
        if(!checkInputs()){
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});

function checkInputs() {
    const titleValue = $.trim(username.value);
    const descrValue = $.trim(descr.value);
    const budgetValue = $.trim(budget.value);

    console.log(titleValue);console.log(descrValue);console.log(budgetValue);

    let status = false;
    if(titleValue === '') {
        status = setErrorFor(title, 'Inserisci un titolo');
    }else{
        status = setSuccessFor(title);
    }

    if(descrValue === '') {
        status = setErrorFor(descr, 'Inserisci una descrizione');
    }else {
        status = setSuccessFor(descr);
    }

    if(budgetValue === '') {
        status = setErrorFor(budget, 'Inserisci un budget');
    } else {
        status = setSuccessFor(budget);
    }

    /*
    if(category === '') {
        status = setErrorFor(budget, 'Seleziona una categoria');
    }else{
        status = setSuccessFor(budget);
    }*/
    return status;
}


function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const formControl = $(input).parent();
    const small = $(formControl).find('small');
    $(formControl).prop('classList', 'form-control error');
    small.append(message);
    return false;
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = $(input).parent();
    $(formControl).prop('classList', 'form-control success');
    return true;
}
```

here is the html (i know it's long sorry):

```
<form action = "projects/post_project.php" method ="post" id="form">
            <div class="form-control">
                <div class = "legend">Scegli un titolo per il tuo progetto</div>   
                <div><input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder = "es.   Sito web per una piccola impresa" rows="5"></div>
                <small></small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <div class = "legend">Dicci di più sul tuo progetto</div>
                <div><textarea rows = "5" id = "descr" type="text" name="descr" placeholder = "Descrivi il tuo progetto"></textarea></div>
                <small></small>
            </div>

            <div class="form-control">
                <div class = "legend">Qual è il tuo budget?</div>
                <select name="budget" id="budget">
                    <option>0€ - 250€</option>
                    <option>250€ - 750€</option>
                    <option>750€ - 1500€-</option>
                    <option>1500€ - 3000€</option>
                    <option>3000€ - 5000€</option>
                    <option>+ 5000€</option>
                </select>
                <small></small>
            </div>

                <!-- Pulsanti per scegliere la categoria -->
                <div class = "legend">In che categoria inseriresti il tuo progetto? </div>
                <small></small>
                    <div class = "category-list">      
                            <input type = "radio" name = "category" value = "web" id = "radio1"> 
                            <label class = "category" for = 'radio1'>
                                <img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/web.png">
                                <span>Web</span>    
                            </label> 

                            <input type = "radio" name = "category" value = "app" id = "radio2">
                            <label class = "category" for = 'radio2'>
                                <img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/app.png">
                                <span>App</span>
                            </label>

                            <input type = "radio" name = "category" value = "database" id = "radio3"> 
                            <label class = "category" for = 'radio3'>
                                <img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/database.png">
                                <span>Database</span>
                            </label>    
                    </div>

                    <div class = "category-list">
                            <input type = "radio" name = "category" value = "software" id = "radio4"> 
                            <label class = "category" for = 'radio4'>
                                <img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/software.png">
                                <span>Software</span>
                            </label>

                            <input type = "radio" name = "category" value = "sistemi" id = "radio5"> 
                            <label class = "category" for = 'radio5'>
                                <img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/sistemi.png">
                                <span>Sistemi</span>
                            </label>

                            <input type = "radio" name = "category" value = "altro" id = "radio6"> 
                            <label class = "category" for = 'radio6'>
                                <img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/other.png">
                                <span>Altro</span>
                            </label>
                    </div> 
                <!-- Fine pulsanti categoria -->

                <div class = "btn"><input type="submit" value="Pubblica"></div>
        </form>
```

here is the css:

```
.form-control.success input {
   border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input {
   border-color: #e74c3c;
}

.form-control small {
   color: #e74c3c;
   font-size: 11pt;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control.error small {
   visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: the first line in your `validateInputs()` is checking the value of a field called `username` but I do not see that field in your HTML.  Is that a copy/paste from the login validation?  It seems like it should be `title` instead

Comment: Where is `username` defined?

Comment: ok i change username with title but stil no working

Comment: Also, `descr.value` and `budget.value` would be undefined. You would want to use `.val()`.

Comment: You also reported no Errors in console, but you have things written to console, do you see any values in console?

Comment: in console i see empty string

Comment: now something work, the title input become red but not show the error message, the select work and the textbox still no working

Comment: You have a drastic logic error. You run an `if()` for each one and change the `status` but this causes each previous check to be over written.

Comment: No no it's correct because on the login/signup page it work perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, you define `status` as `false` and then use a number of IF statements to check for empty fields. As you perform each check, `status` gets updated to a new value. This means that regardless of the other checks, the last check is the only one that counts. With 3 checks it might be like:

```
status = false;
status = false;
status = true;
```

So the result would be `true`.

Consider the following code.

```js
$(function() {
  var form = $('#form');
  var title = $('#title');
  var descr = $('#descr');
  var budget = $('#budget');

  function checkInputs() {
    var titleValue = title.val().trim();
    var descrValue = descr.val().trim();
    var budgetValue = budget.val().trim();
    var status = true;
    if (titleValue === '') {
      status = status && setErrorFor(title, 'Inserisci un titolo');
    } else {
      status = status && setSuccessFor(title);
    }

    if (descrValue === '') {
      status = status && setErrorFor(descr, 'Inserisci una descrizione');
    } else {
      status = status && setSuccessFor(descr);
    }

    if (budgetValue === '') {
      status = status && setErrorFor(budget, 'Inserisci un budget');
    } else {
      status = status && setSuccessFor(budget);
    }

    console.log("Status", status);

    return status;
  }


  function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    var formControl = $(input).parent();
    var small = $("small", formControl);
    $(formControl).prop('classList', 'form-control error');
    small.append(message);
    return false;
  }

  function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const formControl = $(input).parent();
    $(formControl).prop('classList', 'form-control success');
    return true;
  }

  form.submit(e => {
    if (!checkInputs()) {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-control.success input {
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input {
  border-color: #e74c3c;
}

.form-control small {
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 11pt;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control.error small {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="projects/post_project.php" method="post" id="form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <div class="legend">Scegli un titolo per il tuo progetto</div>
    <div><input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="es.   Sito web per una piccola impresa" rows="5"></div>
    <small></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <div class="legend">Dicci di più sul tuo progetto</div>
    <div><textarea rows="5" id="descr" type="text" name="descr" placeholder="Descrivi il tuo progetto"></textarea></div>
    <small></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <div class="legend">Qual è il tuo budget?</div>
    <select name="budget" id="budget">
      <option>0€ - 250€</option>
      <option>250€ - 750€</option>
      <option>750€ - 1500€-</option>
      <option>1500€ - 3000€</option>
      <option>3000€ - 5000€</option>
      <option>+ 5000€</option>
    </select>
    <small></small>
  </div>
  <!-- Pulsanti per scegliere la categoria -->
  <div class="legend">In che categoria inseriresti il tuo progetto? </div>
  <small></small>
  <div class="category-list">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="web" id="radio1">
    <label class="category" for='radio1'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/web.png"><span>Web</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="app" id="radio2">
    <label class="category" for='radio2'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/app.png"><span>App</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="database" id="radio3">
    <label class="category" for='radio3'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/database.png"><span>Database</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="category-list">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="software" id="radio4">
    <label class="category" for='radio4'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/software.png"> <span>Software</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="sistemi" id="radio5">
    <label class="category" for='radio5'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/sistemi.png"><span>Sistemi</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="altro" id="radio6">
    <label class="category" for='radio6'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/other.png"><span>Altro</span></label>
  </div>
  <!-- Fine pulsanti categoria -->
  <div class="btn"><input type="submit" value="Pubblica"></div>
</form>
```

You might also consider performing the check on `blur` event so the User gets feedback as they move through the form.

```js
$(function() {
  var form = $('#form');
  var errs = {
    title: 'Inserisci un titolo',
    descr: 'Inserisci una descrizione',
    budget: 'Inserisci un budget',
  };

  function isEmpty(el) {
    return $(el).val().length === 0;
  }

  function showError(el) {
    var formControl = $(el).closest(".form-control");
    formControl.removeClass("success").addClass("error");
    $("small", formControl).html(errs[$(el).attr("id")]);
  }

  function hideError(el) {
    var formControl = $(el).closest(".form-control");
    formControl.removeClass("error").addClass("success");
    $("small", formControl).html("");
  }

  $("#title, #descr, #budget").blur(function(e) {
    var formControl = $(this).parent();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    if (isEmpty(this)) {
      formControl.addClass("error");
      showError(this);
    } else {
      formControl.addClass("success");
      hideError(this);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.form-control.success input,
.form-control.success textarea,
.form-control.success select {
  border-color: #2ecc71;
}

.form-control.error input,
.form-control.error textarea,
.form-control.error select {
  border-color: #e74c3c;
}

.form-control small {
  color: #e74c3c;
  font-size: 11pt;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.form-control.error small {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="projects/post_project.php" method="post" id="form">
  <div class="form-control">
    <div class="legend">Scegli un titolo per il tuo progetto</div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" name="title" id="title" placeholder="es.   Sito web per una piccola impresa" rows="5">
    </div>
    <small></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <div class="legend">Dicci di più sul tuo progetto</div>
    <div>
      <textarea rows="5" id="descr" type="text" name="descr" placeholder="Descrivi il tuo progetto"></textarea>
    </div>
    <small></small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-control">
    <div class="legend">Qual è il tuo budget?</div>
    <select name="budget" id="budget">
      <option></option>
      <option>0€ - 250€</option>
      <option>250€ - 750€</option>
      <option>750€ - 1500€-</option>
      <option>1500€ - 3000€</option>
      <option>3000€ - 5000€</option>
      <option>+ 5000€</option>
    </select>
    <small></small>
  </div>
  <!-- Pulsanti per scegliere la categoria -->
  <div class="legend">In che categoria inseriresti il tuo progetto? </div>
  <small></small>
  <div class="category-list">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="web" id="radio1">
    <label class="category" for='radio1'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/web.png"><span>Web</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="app" id="radio2">
    <label class="category" for='radio2'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/app.png"><span>App</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="database" id="radio3">
    <label class="category" for='radio3'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/database.png"><span>Database</span></label>
  </div>
  <div class="category-list">
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="software" id="radio4">
    <label class="category" for='radio4'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/software.png"> <span>Software</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="sistemi" id="radio5">
    <label class="category" for='radio5'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/sistemi.png"><span>Sistemi</span></label>
    <input type="radio" name="category" value="altro" id="radio6">
    <label class="category" for='radio6'><img class = "menu-icon" src = "img/other.png"><span>Altro</span></label>
  </div>
  <!-- Fine pulsanti categoria -->
  <div class="btn"><input type="submit" value="Pubblica"></div>
</form>
```